# Optimal DVD video settings

Tags: video, ffmpeg, dvd-burning

I have a 17 GB 1080p HD video file that is saved as MOV. From this one file I need to create a movie DVD with a menu. To create the DVD I will use ConvertXToDVD. The entire video is 1 hour 33 min long. This must be written to a "plain" DVD that only has 4.7 GB of space. I can cut the video into 2 parts, but they will be uneven (~30 min and ~1 hour). How should I convert these videos properly so that the loss of quality would be as minimal as possible.

EDIT: Here is the `ffprobe` output:

```
ffprobe version N-60592-gfd982f2 Copyright (c) 2007-2014 the FFmpeg developers
  built on Feb 13 2014 22:01:02 with gcc 4.8.2 (GCC)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --disable-w32threads --    enable-avisynth --enable-bzlib --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libcaca --enable-libfreetype --enable-libgsm --enable-libilbc --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-librtmp --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvo-aacenc --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libx264 --enable-libxavs --enable-libxvid --enable-zlib
  libavutil      52. 63.101 / 52. 63.101
  libavcodec     55. 52.101 / 55. 52.101
  libavformat    55. 32.101 / 55. 32.101
  libavdevice    55.  9.100 / 55.  9.100
  libavfilter     4.  1.102 /  4.  1.102
  libswscale      2.  5.101 /  2.  5.101
  libswresample   0. 17.104 /  0. 17.104
  libpostproc    52.  3.100 / 52.  3.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'Final.mov':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : qt
    minor_version   : 537199360
    compatible_brands: qt
    creation_time   : 2015-09-19 06:13:23
  Duration: 01:33:17.56, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 26173 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(eng): Audio: pcm_s16le (sowt / 0x74776F73), 48000 Hz, stereo, s16, 1536 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2015-09-19 06:13:23
      handler_name    : Apple Alias Data Handler
    Stream #0:1(eng): Video: h264 (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, bt709), 1920x1080, 24633 kb/s, 29.97 fps, 29.97 tbr, 2997 tbn, 5994 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2015-09-19 06:13:23
      handler_name    : Apple Alias Data Handler
```

Comment: Different file extensions have different compression ratios.

Comment: @Gerasimos.Zap: I know that different file _formats_ have different compression, but if you didn't notice, this question is specifically about a **movie DVD**, which only supports a very specific format (well, technically two: PAL (Europe) and NTSC (Other) though most players support both).

Comment: You're looking for highest quality I presume? Does ConvertXToDVD re encode the video for you, or do you have to do that before hand (if it does re encoding there's not much you can do..)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you get to do the initial (re) encoding yourself:

According to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DVD-Video#Video_data you can encode the video at max 9.8 Mb/s.  FFmpeg has a command line option `-target ntsc-dvd` which seems to setup options appropriate for typical DVD style encode, though possibly not "optimal" lossiness just a default DVD style encode.  You might be able to tweak it to get better like specifying higher max bitrate or higher average bitrate (the "b:v" and possibly "maxrate" options mentioned http://todayiwantedtoprogram.tumblr.com/post/15142587796/what-does-ffmpegs-target-pal-dvd-actually-do and possibly some of the other suggestions) for instance apple's dvd encoder uses a target bitrate of [8 Mbps](https://documentation.apple.com/en/dvdstudiopro/usermanual/index.html#chapter=4%26section=6).  When adjusting maxrate you just have to make sure that max + audio doesn't exceed 10.08 Mbps.

The suggestion for using two pass encoding might be helpful as well, to improve quality.  Basically, you're going to want to basically use the "highest quality level" that ends up still fitting on the disk you're writing to (that still satisfies the DVD spec, of course) 4.7 GB.

Apparently there is no minimum bitrate really so that's OK.